# apt-get fails in Debian and Ubuntu based docker images

Tags: docker, debian, http-status-code-404, apt-get

I get this weird error when trying to run apt-get update in a Debian or Ubuntu docker image:

```
root@60931d7602e1:/# apt-get update
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates Release
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates Release
Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

Err http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  NOT FOUND [IP: 149.20.20.6 80]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
  404  NOT FOUND [IP: 176.9.184.93 80]
Err http://httpredir.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  NOT FOUND [IP: 176.9.184.93 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  NOT FOUND [IP: 149.20.20.6 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  NOT FOUND [IP: 176.9.184.93 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  NOT FOUND [IP: 176.9.184.93 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I checked and the URLs don't exist, it should be .gz or .bz2 instead. It only occurs on one host server (Running Ubuntu), works fine in boot2docker and Debian so far.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this was due to an IP Tables rule that we had set up on the server which redirected port 80 to localhost port 5000. It was accidentally set up in both directions.

The apt-get was requesting the URL's without .gz / .bz2 because it had already failed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You receive `Failed to fetch` error because of the network issues with your instance. The most likely it is either caching proxy or a bad mirror. The easiest way to solve this is to use VPN connection to fetch packages update from other geo location, which will trigger different mirror.